# How to rewrite a basic action/reducer to use promises

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm having trouble understanding how to rewrite normal action/reducer code to make use of redux-thunk or redux-promise-middleware so I can use promises.

I want to wait for my updatePhone to finish updating my `state.user.information.phone` before it starts testUserPhone. So obviously I need a promise to be returned from `updatePhone`.

```js
this.props.updatePhone('+1**********')
.then(() => this.props.testUserPhone(this.props.user.information.phone))
```

action

```
export const updatePhone = (phone) => ({
    type: UPDATE_PHONE,
    payload: phone
})
```

and reducer

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_PHONE':
            return {...state, 
                information: {
                    ...state.information,
                    phone: action.payload
                }
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

---

Should I write something like this as well as the basic function, or can I somehow combine them into one? Because I need the action to fully complete its cycle through my reducer and update `phone` before it comes back, but I don't want to break my reducer because now it won't be able to access `payload` and such since it's inside of a returned function -- super confused with how you start off using these libraries.

```
export function updatePhoneAsync(phone) {
    return dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_PHONE,
        payload: phone
    })
}
```

---

EDIT: So I've got this now for my action creators

```
export const updatePhone = (phone) => ({
    type: UPDATE_PHONE,
    payload: phone
})

export function updatePhoneAsync(phone) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(updatePhone(phone))
    }
}
```

Outside in my component;

```
this.props.updatePhoneAsync('+1**********')
.then(() => this.props.testUserPhone(this.props.user.information))
```

Which gives me an error `'cannot read property then of undefined'`

Comment: Have you read it http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html? All you need is just to send request and dispatch your action when it will be done or failed. Also you can dispatch some action when request was started, so you can some loading screen.

Comment: enough to where I've got another whole reducer that pulls from my API working with redux-promise-middleware - but surely there's a simpler way if I just want to wait for some basic update action to reach the store -- that's what I thought redux-thunk helps with

Comment: If you would resolve your promise in action creator it wold look pretty simple.

Comment: oh wait so if I just `.success((result) => console.log(result))
    .error((error) => console.log(error))` ill be able to use this.props.updatePhone('bla') and not have to worry about it making it all the way through the reducer?

Comment: Check my answer please, probaby it will clarify the situation a bit more.

Comment: You should not do ajax requests and other side effecting things outside of action creators.

Comment: There is no AJAX request here - I just want to wait for my store to update with some user input. Or do you mean the last two lines - they are in a different file

Comment: Ah, that changes things. So you don't need resolving of promises here at all as well as thunk things. Do you want to call testUserPhone function after store will be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write something like this if you use redux-thunk:

Action creators:

```
function update (params if you need them) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        send request here
            .then(data =>
                dispatch(phoneUpdated(data));
}

function phoneUpdated(phone) {
    return {type: 'PHONE_UPDATED', phone};
}
```

Then, feel free to grab this action in your reducer and update the state as you wish.

Also,  you can enhance it with additional actions in case when promise will be rejected, or at the start of request to show loader animations

Comment: so I think I tried what you did there in my edit - but got an error of `cannot read then of undefined` any thoughts?

Comment: You should not resolve promises in your components. Resolve it in action creators and dispatch some actions here, which will be passed to your reducer causing change of state.

Comment: i kind of have to in this case - updatePhone stores the number in Store and then testUserPhone does a backend call and I need to route the user accordingly

Comment: saw edit: isn't that a lot of extra hassle just to check whether a form-input number exists in my Store? is there some other easier thing i can do?